# Send a data to one android phone to another android phone

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, chat

There is a scenario where I have to communicate from one android device to another android device (`Far Away`). But without using any server or sms service. Although I do have an active internet connection. I found a way through GCM, as GCM service provide data upstream as well as data downstream.

I want to know is there anymore way of doing this ?

Comment: The best way is communicating through GCM pushes, Google servers are very reliable.

Comment: GCM does not do device to device, you need to have something in the middle

Comment: @tyczj I just need to share the token of device with another device initially. Rest can be done easily.

Comment: It's highly unlikely you'll be able to do this unless you can ensure each device has a dedicated IP address that never changes.

Comment: @DougStevenson if i ensure dedicated IP, then how could i do is. Directly pinging or communicating with the particular device ?

Comment: It's just regular java socket i/o if you know the IP.  But I'm pretty certain that you will not be able to know.

Answer (score -1):

You need a notification service, and google has something like that for us...

[image]

## how does this works??

Take a look at  the image below,

you need to register your android app in the google service, and your web interface will need an id, so everytime you want to push something to the android, your web interface instead will push it to the google server with the Id of the app, then google (no matter how) will localize your app, and even if its not running, they will get the notification,

behind the scenes there is a couple of thing that you must do, bu nothing like launching rockets from the NASA.

I will suggest to take a look to some [tutorials](http://javapapers.com/android/android-device-to-device-messaging-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-via-http/)
in order to start with the registration of your app, get the api key etc etc..

## In your case

you will need the id of the other phone, so you can push it data.

Comment: I know, what you have stated. As i earlier stated, without using any server,  I have to achieve this.